# Omniture custom link tracking - how to track multiple events

Tags: adobe-analytics, event-tracking

Which property is the right one to pass tracking events when using omniture custom link tracking?

Actually i'm having this three properties:

```
s.linkTrackVars = 'events,prop55';
s.events = ['event12','some other event'];
s.linkTrackEvents = 'event12';
```

but i'm not shure if that this is correct way. Should the `s.events` also be passed to the `s.linkTrackEvents` like:

```
s.linkTrackEvents = s.events;
```

I'm implementing omniture for a customer so i haven't access to the omniture analytics tool.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`linkTrackVars`**](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/linkTrackVars.html) should be a string value and expects a comma delimited list (no spaces) of each variable you want to track, no object namespace prefix. This includes `events` variable if you are tracking events.

[**`linkTrackEvents`**](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/linkTrackEvents.html) should be a string value and expects a comma delimited list (no spaces) of each event you want to track. This should only be the base event itself, not serialization or custom numeric values that you may pop in `events`. For example, if you have `s.events='event1:12345,event2=23';` you should only have `s.linkTrackEvents='event1,event2';`

[**`events`**](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/events.html) should be a string value and expects a comma delimited list (no spaces) of each event you want to track.

**Note:** I noticed you have `events` as an array. Fairly often I see clients do this (and also with `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents`), and then later on within the code (usually within `s_doPlugins`) have code that converts it to string (e.g. `s.events=s.events.join();`). It makes it easier to `.push()` values to it based on whatever logic you have, and this is fine, but to be clear, the official syntax is a comma delimited string, not array, so if you do it as an array, you need to ensure it is converted to a comma delimited string before the `s.t` or `s.tl` call.  As an alternative, there is an [`s.apl` plugin](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/appendList.html) that handles appending values to the string, even ensuring it is unique in the string.

**Examples:**

*Track event1,event2,prop55*

```
s.prop55='some value';
s.events = 'event1,event2';
s.linkTrackEvents = 'event1,event2';
s.linkTrackVars = 'events,prop55';
```

*Track event1 (serialized), event2, prop55*

```
s.prop55='some value';
s.events = 'event1:12345,event2';
s.linkTrackEvents = 'event1,event2';
s.linkTrackVars = 'events,prop55';
```

*Track event1 (custom increment), event2, prop55*

```
s.prop55='some value';
s.events = 'event1=5,event2';
s.linkTrackEvents = 'event1,event2';
s.linkTrackVars = 'events,prop55';
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and the great explanation. This is what i was looking for! Ps. I'm using the `.join(",")` function but forgot to show it in my code snippet.